# Prove that $f(n)=n^{100} \in \Omega(2^{n/100}) $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I know that $f(n)$ grows asymptotically faster than $g(n)$

By definition I know that 
$f(n)=\Omega (g(n))$ given $c$ and $n_0$ such that $f(n) \geq c *g(n), \forall n \geq 1 $

Then I need to show that such $c$ and $n_0$ exist

$$
\Rightarrow n^{100} \geq 2^\frac{n}{100}, \forall n \geq 1\\
 2^\frac{n}{100} = \sqrt[100]{2^n} \\
\Rightarrow n^{100} \geq \sqrt[100]{2^n}\\
\Rightarrow 2n^{100} \geq 2\sqrt[100]{2^n}\\
\therefore f(n)=n^{100} \geq 2\sqrt[100]{2^n}, \forall n\geq1
$$
But this last step isn't true, how to find the $c$ that multiplies $g(n)$ if every constant makes false the last assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that there's an issue; in fact,
$$n^{100}=o\left(2^{n/100}\right).$$
If $n^{100}$ were $\Omega\left(2^{n/100}\right)$, then there would be some constant $c$ for which
$$n^{100}\geq c2^{n/100}$$
for large $n$, which implies
$$n^{10000}\geq C2^n$$
for some constant $C=c^{100}$. Taking $n=2^m$ for large $m$, we need
$$2^{10000m}\geq C2^{2^m}.$$
Can you finish the proof from here to show a contradiction?

Comment: I took the limit of $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and the result was 0, the definition says that if that limit is 0 then $f(n)=o(g(n))$ as you said, thank you so much.